SOLVED: Flutter | Android | Compile error | Sealed classes are not supported as program classes
I'm facing an issue while trying to compile my Flutter project on an Android device. The build fails with the following error message:
Launching lib\main.dart on ASUS X00QD in debug mode...
ERROR:C:\Users\***\***\***\***\project_folder\build\record_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: com.android.tools.r8.internal.Hc: Sealed classes are not supported as program classes

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :record_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.jvm.environment=android, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=androidJvm}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\***\***\***\***\project_folder\build\record_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             19,7s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.            │
│ To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.      │
│ To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

This is the flutter doctor
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.22631.3737], locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 3.22.2 on channel stable at C:\Users\stman\Documents\Programmazione\AndroidStudio\Flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 761747bfc5 (3 weeks ago), 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
    • Engine revision edd8546116
    • Dart version 3.4.3
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?
Thank you!
EDIT 2024 06 26
Issue solved from this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227160052?pli=1#comment37
That said:
Full support for sealed classes will land in Android Studio Hedgehog / AGP 8.2.
Until that goes stable one can use the latest R8 8.2.x version with previous versions of Android Studio / AGP by merge the following into settings.gradle or settings.gradle.kts:
pluginManagement {
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools:r8:8.2.24")
    }
}

